# ADO.NET disconnected architecture

Tags: ado.net

I have selected only top 10 rows from database in disconnected architecture.  but I wanted to delete the row which is not there in above top 10 selected rows. I e after top 10 any row I want to delete. (data set contains only 10 rows). how to do this. Can anyone please give me the solution. Iam looking forward for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. DataSets technically do not contain rows. DataSet is (in effect) just a collection of DataTable objects. You will have to delete the DataRow from the specific DataTable in the DataSet.

As an example, this removes the first row from the "Orders" DataTable.

```
ds.Tables["Orders"].Rows[0].Delete();
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, but that scenario / requirement doesn't make much sense. You will have to SELECT the records into the DataSet and then delete the row based on some criteria. Then using a SqlDataAdapter to update the database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233823%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Vishwaprasad Sure. Please accept the answer if it addresses your question.

Comment: My question is that suppose I will have a dataset which contains a table with  n number of rows. But while connecting with database using disconnected architecture I will write the query to select only top 8 rows. Now the connection will get disconnect. I want to delete the 9th row but it is not there in dataset table records. How to do this.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much sir

Comment: Off course sir. Answer is very helpful.  Thank you for that. But I didn't get the requirement as per my expectation.